# Two Ajax onclick events

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototype

So I have had to modify some old existing code and add another ajax event to `onclick`
so that it has `onclick="function1(); function2();"`

This was working fine on our testing environment as it is a slow VM but on our live environment it causes some issues as `function1()` has to finished updating some records before `function2()` gets called.

Is there a good way to solve this without modifying the js for `function2()` as this the existing code which is called by other events.

Thanks

Comment: function2 won't run until function1 is finished. unless you use asyncronious ajax requests, in that case use callbacks.

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:prototype], do you mean [tag:prototypejs]?

Comment: Yep I do mean prototypejs

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with an example that runs with PrototypeJS

Comment: is `async: false,` helpful for you? Just make the functions synchronize so function 2 will not execute unless function 1 returns your expected value.

Answer (score 0):

Call function2 upon returning from function1:

```
function function1() {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "urlGoesHere",
    data: " ",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        //call function2

    },
    error: 
});

}
```

Or wrap them in a function that calls both 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you use Prototype JS and AJAX because of your tags. You should use a callback function:

```
function function1(callback) {
    new Ajax.Request('http://www.google.nl', {
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}

function function2(callback) {
    new Ajax.Request('http://www.google.nl', {
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}

function both() {
    function1(function() {
        function2();
    });
}
```

Then use `onclick="both();"` on your html element.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EzU4p/

Comment: I don't think the way you mentioned is valid. please test it once.

Comment: You were right, there were lots of errors in my code. jsfiddle was down yesterday. I included a working example now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use always callback of ajax method, check out always callback of $.ajax() method http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

The callback given to  opiton is executed when the ajax request finishes. Here is a suggestion :

```
function function1() {

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/some/page",
        data: " ",
        dataType: "dataType",
    }).always(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == 'success') {
            function2();
        } else {
            errorCallback(jqXHR);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax has `async` property which can be set false. This way, you can wait for that function to complete it's call and set some value. It actually defeats the purpose of AJAX but it may save your day.

I recently had similar issues and somehow calling function2 after completing function1 worked perfectly. My initial efforts to call function2 on function1 success didn't work.

```
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "default.aspx/function1",
                data: "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false, // to make function Sync
                success: function (msg) {
                    var $data = msg.d;
                    if ($data == 1)
                    {
                        isSuccess = 'yes'
                    }
                },

                error: function () {
                    alert('Error in function1');
                }
            });

            // END OF AJAX

           if (isSuccess == 'yes') {
                // Call function 2
           }
```